# Android :CheckBox can't show in the Activity, ERROR : Java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-checkbox

i just want to ask, i got an error when i want to run this `MainActivity`, it's says  `java.lang.NullPointerexecption`, i don't know why this is happening, heres my code,

`CustomAdapter.java`

```
 package com.example.search;

import com.example.database.search.Jurusan;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Jurusan>
{
Jurusan[] modelItems = null;
Context context;

public CustomAdapter(Context context, Jurusan[] resource) {
    super(context,R.layout.row,resource);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.context = context;
    this.modelItems = resource;
 }
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
    //setting layout
    TextView name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);

    name.setText(modelItems[position].getName());

       if(modelItems[position].getValue() == 1)
        cb.setChecked(true);
    else
        cb.setChecked(false); 
    return convertView; 
   }
}
```

and i have `MainActivity.java`

```
 package com.example.search;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import com.example.database.search.Jurusan;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.ListView;
public class CreateData_J extends Activity
{

ListView lv;
Jurusan[] modelItems;

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
 {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.create_data_j);
     lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

     modelItems = new Jurusan[5];
     modelItems[0] = new Jurusan("pizza", 0);
     modelItems[1] = new Jurusan("burger", 1);
     modelItems[2] = new Jurusan("olives", 1); 
     modelItems[3] = new Jurusan("orange", 0); 
     modelItems[4] = new Jurusan("tomato", 1); 
     CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, modelItems);
     lv.setAdapter(adapter); 
 }


 }
```

this is my `Jurusan.java`

```
public class Jurusan
{
    String name;
    int value; /* 0 -> checkbox disable, 1 -> checkbox enable */

 Model(String name, int value)
 {
     this.name = name;
     this.value = value;
 }
 public String getName()
 {
     return this.name;
 }
 public int getValue()
 {
     return this.value;
 }

 }
```

> **this is my error track**

```
 04-09 11:58:33.765: E/AndroidRuntime(22047): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 04-09 11:58:33.765: E/AndroidRuntime(22047): java.lang.NullPointerException
 04-09 11:58:33.765: E/AndroidRuntime(22047):   at            com.example.search.CustomAdapter.getView(CustomAdapter.java:35)
 04-09 11:58:33.765: E/AndroidRuntime(22047):   at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2159)
 04-09 11:58:33.765: E/AndroidRuntime(22047):   at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1246)
 04-09 11:58:33.765: E/AndroidRuntime(22047):   at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1158)
 04-09 11:58:33.765: E/AndroidRuntime(22047):   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15592)
 04-09 11:58:33.765: E/AndroidRuntime(22047):   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
 04-09 11:58:33.765: E/AndroidRuntime(22047):   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
 04-09 11:58:33.765: E/AndroidRuntime(22047):   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
 04-09 11:58:33.765: E/AndroidRuntime(22047):   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
 04-09 11:58:33.765: E/AndroidRuntime(22047):   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15592)
 04-09 11:58:33.765: E/AndroidRuntime(22047):   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
 04-09 11:58:33.765: E/AndroidRuntime(22047):   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
 04-09 11:58:33.765: E/AndroidRuntime(22047):   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15592)
 04-09 11:58:33.765: E/AndroidRuntime(22047):   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:847)
 04-09 11:58:33.765: E/AndroidRuntime(22047):   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
 04-09 11:58:33.765: E/AndroidRuntime(22047):   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15592)
 04-09 11:58:33.765: E/AndroidRuntime(22047):   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
 04-09 11:58:33.765: E/AndroidRuntime(22047):   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
 04-09 11:58:33.765: E/AndroidRuntime(22047):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2180)
 04-09 11:58:33.765: E/AndroidRuntime(22047):   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15592)
 04-09 11:58:33.765: E/AndroidRuntime(22047):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1878)
 04-09 11:58:33.765: E/AndroidRuntime(22047):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1089)
 04-09 11:58:33.765: E/AndroidRuntime(22047):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1265)
 04-09 11:58:33.765: E/AndroidRuntime(22047):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:989)
 04-09 11:58:33.765: E/AndroidRuntime(22047):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4356)
 04-09 11:58:33.765: E/AndroidRuntime(22047):   at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
 04-09 11:58:33.765: E/AndroidRuntime(22047):   at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
 04-09 11:58:33.765: E/AndroidRuntime(22047):   at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
 04-09 11:58:33.765: E/AndroidRuntime(22047):   at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
 04-09 11:58:33.765: E/AndroidRuntime(22047):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
 04-09 11:58:33.765: E/AndroidRuntime(22047):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
 04-09 11:58:33.765: E/AndroidRuntime(22047):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
 04-09 11:58:33.765: E/AndroidRuntime(22047):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5099)
 04-09 11:58:33.765: E/AndroidRuntime(22047):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 04-09 11:58:33.765: E/AndroidRuntime(22047):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
 04-09 11:58:33.765: E/AndroidRuntime(22047):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:803)
 04-09 11:58:33.765: E/AndroidRuntime(22047):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:570)
 04-09 11:58:33.765: E/AndroidRuntime(22047):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Can anyone help me about this error, any help is needed thank you, sorry about my bad
 english. Thank you

here is my row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:orientation="horizontal" >
 <CheckBox
 android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:text="" />
 <TextView
 android:id="@+id/textView1"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:text="TextView" />
</LinearLayout>
```

and this my activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical" >
 <ListView
 android:id="@+id/listView1"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
 </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: please indicate line 35 @ `CustomAdapter`

Comment: Hum.. @shayanpourvatan line 35 will be better ;)

Comment: @Fllo you right, i edit that, typo mistake

Comment: its null because modelItems has no values.

Comment: @Achilles `this.modelItems = resource;`

Comment: @shayanpourvatan hmm? line 35 > it's about the method getView right? can u tell where the wrong code?

Comment: @shayanpourvatan it can also happen that he is passing null array.

Comment: @Achilles OP post `CreateData_J` class to, array is not null, please see that

Comment: what is modelItems[position].getNama_jurusan()? can not see it in your Model class? And please post row.xml

Comment: @ndr_sd witch line is 35?

Comment: @ndr_sd show your row layout file.

Comment: @LazyNinja : sorry i have change the code, it's should be getName(), and i already post the xml file :D

Comment: @ndr_sd can you post Jurusan class instead of Model class?

Comment: @LazyNinja : the id of checkbox is android:id="@+id/checkBox1" and the id of textview is android:id="@+id/textView1"....

Comment: @ndr_sd you not indicated line 35 so far.

Comment: @LazyNinja : i already did, sorry wrong class i post before

Comment: @shayanpourvatan:i already indicate, it's getView method right?

Comment: clean your project and try again, because all thing is OK in my look

Comment: try inflate your layout as Lazy said in answer ( i mean change `LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();` to  `LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);`

Comment: @shayanpourvatan : i already did, but it's still error :(

Answer (score 0):

According to you error log it seems you have null pointer exception in you adapter class at the line

```
name.setText(modelItems[position].getName());
```

this means "name" is not getting right from layout means your layout is not being came in the control of adapter to do modifications.
so i am revising your adapters code 
try this hope it would solve the problem.

```
package com.example.search;

import com.example.database.search.Jurusan;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.TextView;

    public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Jurusan>
    {
     Jurusan[] modelItems = null;
     Context context;

   public CustomAdapter(Context context, Jurusan[] resource) {
   super();
   // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
   this.context = context;
   this.modelItems = resource;
   }


   @Override
   public View getView(int position, View convertview, ViewGroup parent) 
    {

      View convertView = convertview;
      if (convertView == null) {
          convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(
                R.layout.row, null);
        }

    TextView name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);

    name.setText(modelItems[position].getName());

     if(modelItems[position].getValue() == 1)
       cb.setChecked(true);
    else
       cb.setChecked(false); 


   return convertView; 
  }
}
```

If it is helpful then **Vote Up**

If you have any questions, I am here to answer them.

Comment: i think variable covertVew is duplicate, with the parameter? what should i do? @Nitij Katiyar

Comment: i have edited my answer that was misspelled the convertView inside the argument of getview method will have a "small v" like convetrview.
now you can try this. @ndr_sd

Answer (score 0):

Try to change

```
LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
```

to

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
```

Even if the above works, you should try to check if convertView is null before inflating it. Because it will drain your resources if you leave it like this.

Comment: remove this line super(context,R.layout.row,resource);  in the constructor, please see my edit @ndr_sd

Comment: @LazyNinja if OP don't send array to super constructor, list not generated , because in `ArrayAdapter` that line handle `getCount()` and other thing

Comment: it need super constructor, so i can remove it.. @Lazy Ninja

Comment: @shayanpourvatan is right, don't remove it since you are using an ArrayAdapter

Comment: @ndr_sd did you change `LayoutInflater` with this code? if yes problem is your id, check all file and make sure you xml layout,

Comment: @ndr_sd your code seems alright. Double check as shayan said. If it still persists go through this http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/listview/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-arrayadapter/

Comment: @LazyNinja : thanks for the tutorial now my code is working.. Thanksss a lottt :D